# mvc Api optimization: return ihhtpresult from a custom class to api action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, optimization

I am working with C#, MVC , ASP.Net Web API and I realized that I have code that is repeated in my API controller.

```
public IHttpActionResult PutSomething( string ParameterId)
{
    var MyObject= _dbContext.objeto.Where(c => c.myId== ParameterId);

    var MyDto= MyObject.FirstOrDefault();
    MyDto.Visible = false;
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    return Ok();
}
```

The only thing that changes from one action to another is this part

```
MyDto.Visible = false;
```

to

```
MyDto.Visible = true;
```

So my idea is to add a custom class called : `Class1`

```
public class Class1
{      
    public xxxx MyReuseMethod(bool istrueorfalse)
    {
        var MyObject= _dbContext.objeto.Where(c => c.myId== ParameterId);
        /*do some validations, if do not pass*/ return badrequest();
        var MyDto= MyObject.FirstOrDefault();
        MyDto.Visible = istrueorfalse;
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

and call it in my api actions:

```
var Reuse=new class1();
class1.MyReuseMethod(true);
```

Can you tell me please, what kind of return should I give to `MyReuseMethod`, so I can return `Ok()`, `BadRequest()`, `NotFound()`, etc...?

Comment: Likely, it should return IActionResult, or ActionResult. You should know this based on the return type in the controller where you moved the code from. What does the function in the controller return?

Comment: the action from the api is an IhttpActionResult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it return a flag you can use in the controller.

```
public interface IDtoService {
    bool? MyReuseMethod(string ParameterId, bool istrueorfalse);
}

public class MyDtoServie : IDtoService {
    private MyDbContext dbContext;

    public MyDtoServie(MyDbContext dbContext) {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public bool? MyReuseMethod(string ParameterId, bool istrueorfalse) {
        var MyObject = dbContext.objeto.Where(c => c.myId == ParameterId);
        var MyDto = MyObject.FirstOrDefault();
        if(MDto == null) return null;

        if(!/*do some validations, if do not pass*/ ) {
            return false;
        }

        MyDto.Visible = istrueorfalse;            
        return dbContext.SaveChanges() > 0;
    }
}
```

Then in the controller return the necessary result based on the flag returned.

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController {
    private readonly IDtoService dtoService;

    public MyApiController (IDtoService dtoService) {
        this.dtoService = dtoService;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult PutSomething(string ParameterId) {
        var result = dtoService.MyReuseMethod(ParameterId, false);
        if(result == null) return NotFound();
        if(result == false) return BadRequest();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Try not to mix concerns when refactoring your code.

`Ok()`, `BadRequest()`, `NotFound()`, etc... are concerns of the controller and should remain in the controller.

Comment: Can you please clarify why we are using IDtoService and making MyDtoServie  inherit from it please?

Comment: Following Dependency Inversion pattern where you classes should depend on abstraction and not concretions. The repeated code was extracted out into a service that can be explicitly injected into dependent classes. Makes your code more flexible and easier to maintain and test.

Comment: great clarification    I was not awared about this implementation way

Comment: @evvk read up more about it documented here [Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection)

Comment: just what I was looking for..I had an error like An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'xxxController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Comment: @evvk that is a standard misleading error. make sure your dependencies are registered with the DI container. The framework throw that error when it can't create the controllers properly. There are many answer here on SO that cover it already

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the abstract base `ApiController` and it will provide the implementations for `Ok()`, `BadRequest()`, etc.

```
public abstract class MyBaseApiController : ApiController
{
    public virtual IHttpActionResult MyReuseMethod(bool isTrueOrFalse)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

I'd separate the query code and just have the controller deal with the Dto models.

```
public abstract class MyBaseApiController : ApiController
{
    public virtual IHttpActionResult MyReuseMethod(MyDto model)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}

public class MyApiController : MyBaseApiController
{
    IMyService service;

    public MyApiController()
    {
        service = new MyService();
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var dto = service.GetItem(id);
        return MyReuseMethod(dto);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods `Ok()`, `BadRequest()` etc are methods available on the `Controller` base class. I wouldn't recommend making these available in your reusable class since this would tightly couple your code to a particular implementation of MVC. Instead, you could make your method a `void` method and return `Ok()` from your controller method below the call to your new class method.

Comment: Thanks , It was good inforrmation to keep in mind! I could have had problems with my code quality